# Excel VBA copy contents to a specific date

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have a problem, I need to fill some cells with info that came from a database, the thing is that I need to copy the info to a different sheet by date, here's the info that I need.

For example, today (05/27/2021) I have this data:

```
RCHCV   0
RCHSV   3
RLCCV   3
RLCSV   1
RPCV    1
RPSV    0
RDVCV   0
RDVSV   0
RAyOB/V 0
```

and I need it to copy to a list:

```
may-24-21   26  8   1   7   0   48  76  8   68  1
may-25-21   8   2   1   1   0   57  98  7   91  5
may-26-21   10  8   0   8   0   30  79  10  67  2
may-27-21   (values goes here)
```

So, I have this button that copies the text, but I don't know how to "find" the correct cells to paste the info...

Comment: There's a whole lot of missing information in your post.  What order do things go in (9 items for today with 10 columns), what happens with the button you have, what have you tried so far?

Comment: what is the code behind the button? How does today's data translate into the dated lists?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in **range A1:A9** and you want to copy it to **column D**, right next to date, which is in **column C**:

```
Sub test()
    Dim today As Date
    Dim your_vals As Variant
    Dim date_col As Range
    
    today = Date
    your_vals = Range("A1:A9").Value
    Set date_col = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C")
    
    On Error GoTo err
        date_col.Find(today, SearchOrder:=xlPrevious).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, UBound(your_vals, 1)).Value _
            = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(your_vals)
    On Error GoTo -1
    
    Exit Sub
    
err:
    MsgBox ("Today's date not found!")
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm going to try this and see if I can get you more info about it, actually there are about 50 cells with data